# SingleOutputEcospold1Importer returns "NameError: name 'filename' is not defined"

Tags: import, filenames, brightway

I'm trying to import ecoinvent 3.4 cutoff database so I wrote:

```
import brightway2 as bw
```

[...]

```
fpei34 = r'C:\Users\Me\Anaconda3\ecoinvent 3.4_cutoff_ecoSpold02\MasterData'

if 'ecoinvent 3.4 cutoff' in bw.databases:
    print("Database has already been imported")
else:
    ei34 = bw.SingleOutputEcospold1Importer(fpei34, 'ecoinvent 3.4 cutoff')
    ei34.apply_strategies()
    ei34.statistics()
```

I get the answer:

> NameError: name 'filename' is not defined.

It also indicates the problem occurs at the line where `SingleOutputEcospold1Importer` is used.

Do you know what is the mistake I did and how I could arrange the code?

Comment: To get an answer for this question, you need to provide more information. Copy/pasting the traceback would be a good start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least two problems with your code:
  - You are using the `SingleOutputEcospold1Importer` importer. The ecoinvent database has moved to ecoSpold2 files as of ecoinvent v3, so you should use the `SingleOutputEcospold2Importer` instead.
 - Your filepath `fpei34` seems to be for masterdata, and not the datasets per se. You should be looking for a folder named `datasets` with over 14000 spold files instead.